# How generate several Include() at runtime in a repository

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a `Customer` class the Customer can have several `Address`

In my repository I have this :

```
protected DbSet<T> Table;
```

and this method :

```
public T Find<TIncludeField>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where,
    Expression<Func<T, TIncludeField>> include)
    => Table.Where(@where).Include(include).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I can use it like this :

```
_customerRepo.Find(x => x.Reference.ToLower() == reference.ToLower(), x => x.Addresses);
```

I'd like to able to do this :

```
public T Find<TIncludeField>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where,
    Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TIncludeField>>> includes)
    => Table.Where(@where).Include(includes).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I don't know how create at runtime a list of `.Include(includes)`

Any idea ?

Based on :[Philip Japikse Code](https://github.com/skimedic/dotnetcore_hol/blob/master/Code/Complete/SpyStore_HOL/SpyStore_HOL.DAL/Repos/Base/IRepo.cs)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension method

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludesAll<TIncludeField>(this IQueryable<T> query,
IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, TIncludeField>>> includes)
{
    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        query = query.Include(include);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: This only allow you to include properties if they are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this one (this will allow you to include properties of different types, and the params array allows you to specify zero, one or more includes)

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludesAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        query = query.Include(include);
    }

    return query;
}
```